# use netfilter_queue to copy the packet to user layer is ok, modify the packet and injection to kernel fail

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, iptables

My host os is ubuntu12.04, my iptables version is v1.4.12, libmnl-1.0.3, libnetfilter_queue-1.0.2, libnfnetlink-1.0.1. 
First of all, I execeuted iptable commans "iptables -A -p tcp --dport 80 -J NFQUEUE" to import the ip packet to the NFQUEUE, and then I use libnetfilter_queue to copy the packets to the user layer, and then I modify the payload of the packet, rebuild the ip checksum and tcp checksum. finally, I call nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL) to injection the packet to the kernel. But it doesn't work. I use wireshare to capture the packet, I find than, my own data can't set to the packet.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the verdict function you are using :

```
nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL)
```

the signature is :

`nfq_set_verdict(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, u_int32_t id, u_int32_t verdict, u_int32_t mark, int set_mark, u_int32_t data_len, const unsigned char *data)`

using `0` for length and `NULL` for data pointer, you are accepting packet based on his ID number, not passing your modified payload

you should try with something like that :

```
char *pktData;
u_int32_t len=0;

len = nfq_get_payload(nfa, &pktData);

    // modify payload

return nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, len, pktData);
```

then your modified payload will be transmitted